# Ruler display in VIM is misbehaving inside GNU Screen

Tags: ruler

As I scroll through a .c file in VIM inside GNU screen, using 'down' arrow, the ruler display is misbehaving as you can see in the attached image. This doesn't happen if I press 'page down' key. This doesn't happen outside GNU screen either.

Some of my .screenrc settings are visible in the attached screenshot. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: check your $TERM configuration inside the screen session and also inside vim `:set term?`

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBrabandt  $TERM is always set to screen inside screen. I am not able to change that. 
Adding `:set term` to .vimrc solved the problem.
But everytime I open a file with vim,  I get a warning message "Press ENTER or type command to continue"
Can you please help how to mask this warning. I tried adding `set shortmess=` and 
`set cmdheight=2` It didnt work.

Comment: `:set term` requires an argument.

Comment: Thanks a million @ChristianBrabandt !!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Hi, term setting worked perfectly. It suddenly ceased working for no apparent reason. I've added `TERM=xterm` in .bashrc, `term xterm` in .screenrc, `set term=xterm` and `if &term == "screen" set term=xterm
endif
` in .vimrc. I saw `:echo $TERM` inside a vim file, it rightly showed `xterm`. But still i face the same ruler issue that I've mentioned above. Can you please me to solve this problem?